# OpenFOAM powerlevel10k integration error

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to learn linux to become familiar with opensource CFD tool OpenFOAM. I did everything according to the [installation guide](https://openfoam.org/download/11-ubuntu/) and everything went fine. In Bash I had to add the line `source /opt/openfoam11/etc/bashrc` in my **.bashrc** and if I ran `foamRun -help`, a message appeared ensuring correct binaries were found. Later I installed powerlevel10k to get a better linux experience. So I tried to add the same line in my **.zshrc**. But it was showing an error when I open my terminal.

```
[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.

You can:

  - Recommended: Change ~/.zshrc so that it does not perform console I/O
    after the instant prompt preamble. See the link below for details.

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly and prompt will update smoothly.

  - Suppress this warning either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

  - Disable instant prompt either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start slowly.

  - Do nothing.

    * You will see this error message every time you start zsh.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

For details, see:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#instant-prompt

-- console output produced during zsh initialization follows --

/opt/openfoam11/etc/config.sh/paraview:46: no matches found: /opt/ThirdParty-11/platforms/linux64Gcc/cmake-*
```

I kind of of understand that OpenFOAM comes with default bash configuaration so if I source the bashrc file of openFOAM in zsh it will cause problem. But what is the solution(Xubuntu 22.04.3)?

The bashrc of OpenFOAM contains -

```
#----------------------------------*-sh-*--------------------------------------

# =========                 |

# \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox

#  \\    /   O peration     | Website:  https://openfoam.org

#   \\  /    A nd           | Copyright (C) 2011-2023 OpenFOAM Foundation

#    \\/     M anipulation  |

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# License

#     This file is part of OpenFOAM.

#

#     OpenFOAM is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it

#     under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by

#     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or

#     (at your option) any later version.

#

#     OpenFOAM is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT

#     ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or

#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License

#     for more details.

#

#     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License

#     along with OpenFOAM.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

#

# File

#     etc/bashrc

#

# Description

#     Startup file for OpenFOAM

#     Sourced from ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

#     Should be usable by any POSIX-compliant shell (eg, ksh)

#

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------



export WM_PROJECT=OpenFOAM

export WM_PROJECT_VERSION=11



################################################################################

# USER EDITABLE PART: Changes made here may be lost with the next upgrade

#

# FOAM_INST_DIR is the location of the OpenFOAM installation which defaults to

# the directory containing this file if sourced by a bash shell.

#

# Please set to the appropriate path if the default is not correct.

#

[ "$BASH" -o "$ZSH_NAME" ] && \

#export FOAM_INST_DIR=$(cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE:-$0})/../.. && pwd -P) || \

export FOAM_INST_DIR=/opt

# export FOAM_INST_DIR=~$WM_PROJECT

# export FOAM_INST_DIR=/opt/$WM_PROJECT

# export FOAM_INST_DIR=/usr/local/$WM_PROJECT

#

# END OF (NORMAL) USER EDITABLE PART

################################################################################



# The default environment variables below can be overridden in a prefs.sh file

# located in ~/.OpenFOAM/$WM_PROJECT_VERSION, ~/.OpenFOAM,

# $FOAM_INST_DIR/site/$WM_PROJECT_VERSION or $FOAM_INST_DIR/site



#- Compiler location:

#    WM_COMPILER_TYPE= system | ThirdParty (OpenFOAM)

export WM_COMPILER_TYPE=system



#- Compiler:

#    WM_COMPILER = Gcc | Gcc48 ... Gcc62 | Clang | Icx

export WM_COMPILER=Gcc

unset WM_COMPILER_ARCH WM_COMPILER_LIB_ARCH



#- Memory addressing:

#    On a 64bit OS this can be 32bit or 64bit

#    On a 32bit OS addressing is 32bit and this option is not used

#    WM_ARCH_OPTION = 32 | 64

export WM_ARCH_OPTION=64



#- Precision:

#    WM_PRECISION_OPTION = SP | DP | LP

export WM_PRECISION_OPTION=DP



#- Label size:

#    WM_LABEL_SIZE = 32 | 64

export WM_LABEL_SIZE=32



#- Optimised, debug, profiling:

#    WM_COMPILE_OPTION = Opt | Debug | Prof

export WM_COMPILE_OPTION=Opt



#- MPI implementation:

#    WM_MPLIB = SYSTEMOPENMPI | OPENMPI | SYSTEMMPI | MPICH | MPICH-GM | HPMPI

#               | MPI | FJMPI | QSMPI | SGIMPI | INTELMPI

export WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI



#- Operating System:

#    WM_OSTYPE = POSIX | ???

export WM_OSTYPE=POSIX



#- Floating-point signal handling:

#    set or unset

export FOAM_SIGFPE=



#- memory initialisation:

#    set or unset

#export FOAM_SETNAN=





################################################################################



# The old dirs to be cleaned from the environment variables

foamOldDirs="$WM_PROJECT_DIR $WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR \

    $HOME/$WM_PROJECT/$USER $FOAM_USER_APPBIN $FOAM_USER_LIBBIN \

    $WM_PROJECT_SITE $FOAM_SITE_APPBIN $FOAM_SITE_LIBBIN"



# Location of installation

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

export WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR=$FOAM_INST_DIR

export WM_PROJECT_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/openfoam11



if [ -d "$WM_PROJECT_DIR" ]

then

    WM_PROJECT_DIR_REAL=$(cd $WM_PROJECT_DIR && pwd -P)

    if [ -d "$WM_PROJECT_DIR_REAL" -a -e "$WM_PROJECT_DIR_REAL/etc/bashrc" ]

    then

        export WM_PROJECT_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/openfoam11

    fi

    unset WM_PROJECT_DIR_REAL

fi



# Location of third-party software

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

export WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/ThirdParty-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION



if [ -d "$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR" ]

then

    WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR_REAL=$(cd $WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR && pwd -P)

    if [ -d "$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR_REAL" -a -e "$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR_REAL/etc/tools" ]

    then

        export WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR=$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR_REAL

    fi

    unset WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR_REAL

fi



# Location of site-specific templates etc

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# unset is equivalent to $WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/site

if [ -d "$WM_PROJECT_SITE" ]

then

    export WM_PROJECT_SITE

else

    unset WM_PROJECT_SITE

fi



# Location of user files

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

export WM_PROJECT_USER_DIR=$HOME/$WM_PROJECT/$USER-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION



# Source initialisation functions

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/functions



# Add in preset user or site preferences:

_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile prefs.sh`



# Evaluate command-line parameters of the form "param=keyword" or unset

# parameters with "param="

export FOAM_SETTINGS="$@"

_foamParams $@



# Clean standard environment variables (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, MANPATH)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

foamClean=$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamCleanPath



#- Clean PATH

cleaned=`$foamClean "$PATH" "$foamOldDirs"` && PATH="$cleaned"



#- Clean LD_LIBRARY_PATH

cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$foamOldDirs"` \

    && LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cleaned"



#- Clean MANPATH

cleaned=`$foamClean "$MANPATH" "$foamOldDirs"` && MANPATH="$cleaned"



export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANPATH





# Source project setup files

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

_foamSource $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/settings

_foamSource $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/aliases





# Source user setup files for optional packages

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/mpi`

_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/paraview`

_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/ensight`

_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/gperftools`





# Clean environment paths again. Only remove duplicates

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#- Clean PATH

cleaned=`$foamClean "$PATH"` && PATH="$cleaned"



#- Clean LD_LIBRARY_PATH

cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` && LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cleaned"



#- Clean MANPATH (trailing ':' to find system pages)

cleaned=`$foamClean "$MANPATH"`: && MANPATH="$cleaned"



export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANPATH



#- Clean LD_PRELOAD

if [ -n "$LD_PRELOAD" ]

then

    cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_PRELOAD"` && LD_PRELOAD="$cleaned"

    export LD_PRELOAD

fi





# Cleanup environment:

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

unset cleaned foamClean foamOldDirs





# Unload initialisation functions:

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/functions



# Source the bash completion file:

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[ "$BASH" ] && . $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/bash_completion



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Powerlevel10k is saying that the following error is printed when you start zsh:

```
/opt/openfoam11/etc/config.sh/paraview:46: no matches found: /opt/ThirdParty-11/platforms/linux64Gcc/cmake-*
```

You should see this error even if you disable powerlevel10k. I don't know how exactly you can fix this error but once you do, the error message will disappear.